# '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-8

any solution to this error? I have already tried with the browser settings but the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: Please give us some context. What are you trying to do and when does it happen?

Comment: That means you're not getting JSON back. You're getting an HTML document. This is often the result of an error.

Comment: This isn't a larvel problem its a browser problem. The browser is looking for the sourcemap for those minimized files. But you have some sort of 404 system that generates a HTML file. You can modify the js/css files to remove the reference to the source files or disable the devtools looking for the sourcemaps in the first place.

Comment: I use a template in Laravel and I try to use some plugins in this case color picker and it gives me that error in that view, in others that I use them no, I have already verified the links and all are ok